# Cannot check for an equal number using string

Tags: javascript, if-statement

I have what I thought would be a simple logic check. In my code

```
$scope.seatMap.PlaneTypeCode = "175"
```

However, when I set

```
$scope.seatMap.PlaneTypeCode === "175" //my debugger returns <b>false </b>

parseInt($scope.seatMap.PlaneTypeCode,10) ===175  // equals 17
```

I added a few zeros on the radix but that did nothing to help.

I am not sure how to do a comparison check.  Any insight on this would be hugely appreciated.

Here is my full if statement

```
if (parseInt(col.name,10) ===4 && parseInt($scope.seatMap.PlaneTypeCode,10) ===175 && $scope.TripSummary) {
       col.available = false;
    }
```

****** Changed my response to this

```
if (parseInt(col.name,10) ===4 && $scope.seatMap.PlaneTypeCode ==="175" && $scope.TripSummary) {
            col.available = false;
        }  // still getting false
```

Comment: The first step would be to find out what `console.log($scope.seatMap.PlaneTypeCode);` shows in the console. You don’t have to guess.

Comment: _However, when I set_: you're not using assignment operator, where `=` is assignment, Try `$scope.seatMap.PlaneTypeCode = "175"` instead `$scope.seatMap.PlaneTypeCode === "175"`

Comment: it returned "175".  I am missing something simple here.  just not sure what.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

=== is a best practice, you should use it.  Review the reference provided by @Joyson

You don't need the **,10** in parseInt because it is the default.

```
var PlaneTypeCode = "175";
if (parseInt(PlaneTypeCode) === 175) {
  console.log('equal');
}
```

If **PlaneTypeCode** is a code and can contain anything other than digits, a better comparison would be:

```
if (PlaneTypeCode === "175")
```

Comment: I know this should be the case basic javascript, but I am getting false on this and have been for a while.  there has to be something I am missing.

Comment: if (PlaneTypeCode === "175") would be better since in the first portion of this answer, the  variable is a string and following the parseInt, the comparison value will be converted to a number - hence the fail on the strict comparison

Comment: A radix should continue to be used since not all browsers in use are compliant with ES5, which introduced the default of 10. Also, `0x` will still indicate base 16. Using strict equality can introduce as many issues as it solves, and in this case is illogical. If *PlaneTypeCode* is a string and strict equality is necessary, then `PlaneTypeCode === "175"` should be used since `parseInt(PlaneTypeCode) === 175` is equivalent to `PlaneTypeCode == 175` (i.e. the conversion implicit in `==` is explicit using parseInt, so what's the point?).

Answer (score 1):

You can use == instead of ===

```
$scope.seatMap.PlaneTypeCode == "175"
```

Please refer to [Difference between == and ===](https://stackoverflow.com/a/359509/1694185) to know more

Comment: That was false for me too.  I tried that initially.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

use angular.equals($scope.seatMap.PlaneTypeCode,"175")